# Centering images in paragraphs that uses max-width

Tags: html, css

I’m trying to center images on my blog.

​The code example below illustrates the HTML structure used on the blog.

Unfortunately it does not work with multiple images, only one. Multiple images gets left aligned, I would like them all to be centered. I cannot add or remove anything (classes, spans etc) from the HTML structure. Any happy soul out there who knows a solution? I don’ty want to use Javascript at all, pure CSS if possible.

#### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Centering images</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <article>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            <p><img src="http://media-cache-ec2.pinterest.com/upload/150166968795197906_SMIa24Vz_f.jpg"></p>
            <p><img src="http://media-cache-ec8.pinterest.com/upload/192528952790461003_uuI48luk_f.jpg"></p>
            <p><img src="http://media-cache-ec7.pinterest.com/upload/7318418115018093_x77QiYNG_f.jpg"></p>
            <p><img src="http://media-cache-ec4.pinterest.com/upload/6262886952319256_ke0nvUiH_f.jpg"></p>
            <p><img src="http://media-cache-ec9.pinterest.com/upload/59883870015686497_9yB48yWs_f.jpg"></p>            
            <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </article>
    </div>
</body>
</html>​
```

and here is the CSS:

#### CSS

```
#container {
    width: 100%; 
    text-align: left;    
}

p {    
    max-width: 200px; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}

p > img {
    margin: 0 -100%;
}
```

Here is a link to the example code above that shows the result:
http://jsfiddle.net/ttJGk/37/

Answer (score 2):

You just need a `text-align: center;` on the paragraphs containing images.

I added this CSS rule:

```
p.image-container {
    text-align:center;
}
```

And this class to the paragraphs with images:

```
<p class="image-container">...</p>
```

See my updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ttJGk/41/.

---

This is assuming that you want the images to be full-size, or at least that there is no restriction that they must fit within the 200px `p` tags. If you wanted them to fit within those tags, you could just add a `max-width: inherit;` to the `img` tags. You can also remove the `margin: 0 -100%;`.

This solution will also work if you can absolutely not add any classes to the HTML. See the updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ttJGk/45/.

Comment: From the question: I cannot add or remove anything (**classes**, spans etc) from the HTML structure.

Comment: @JohnLawrence: Thank you, for some reason I read that as "I cannot **remove** anything..." and didn't see the "add" part of that. My edits address this.

Comment: The images all need to be full size, so you latest example is not a solution for me, I’m afraid.

Comment: @EvanFoster: Unfortunately, if that's the case and you can't use the answer from John Lawrence either, then it seems you will have to either use JavaScript or change your HTML...

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your css class like this

```
p > img {
margin: 0 auto;
width:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will always have this structure of text paragraphs first and last in the article, then you could center align everything and use the `:first-child` and `:last-child` pseudo classes to left align the text.

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;    
}


article p:first-child, article p:last-child{
    text-align: left;
}
```

See [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ttJGk/48/)

Comment: Unfortunately, the paragraph structure will always change.

Comment: Than your only option is JS! But if it is your blog, why can't you add a class to the paragraphs. Or do you just don't know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
p img {margin:0 auto; display:block;}
```

This will center all images in paragraphs.